# TeamViewer can't change 640x480 when connecting from android

Tags: teamviewer

I can't change the resolution on my teamviewer when I log in
from my android to my laptop.

I tried to select another resolution in the preferences and then to login again but it didn't do anything
and the resolution in the preferences came back to 640x480 all the time.

I have teamviewer 10 in both my laptop and on my android phone.

How can I resolve this issue?